# Misalign predictions and the response column after crossvalidation in H2O (Deep Learning)

Tags: python, deep-learning, cross-validation, h2o

I keep having a problem with a deep learning model. I have a model trained on rrc data frame, and if I do:

`rrc['preds'] = dp.cross_validation_holdout_predictions().as_data_frame().predict`

I always get misaligned the response columns and predictions. At the top of the data frame there are aligned, but at some point it seems that they are misaligned and if I calculate a correlation between them is very bad because of this misalignment. I have been trying to fix this for over 3 day but I have no idea how to do it.

I'm using H2O 3.10.4.5.
The model itself:

`dp = H2ODeepLearningEstimator(activation = "Tanh", hidden = [10, 10, 10], epochs = 10000, 
                              keep_cross_validation_predictions=True, 
                              ignored_columns = ['fn', 'pdb_id','pdb_id_chain', 'pdb_id_chain_source', 'source'])
dp.train(x = list(set(rrch.col_names) - set(['rmsd_all'])), y ="rmsd_all", training_frame = rrch, 
         fold_column="cv")`

Edit: I think I found the problem (Cell #58) https://github.com/mmagnus/mmagnus.github.io/blob/master/mq-test.ipynb If I do `rrc3 = rrc3[rrc3.rmsd_all < 10]` to remove some rows that rmsd_all (the response column) value is higher than 10 and then I do `rrc3h = h2o.H2OFrame(rrc3)` caused the problem. I'm not sure why though. The dataset, 40mb https://www.dropbox.com/s/1et38o3xx47jw1m/rasp_rnakb_cv2.csv?dl=0

Comment: It would be much quicker to debug this if you provided a fully-reproducible example.  Can you add one?

Comment: Solved: `rrc3.reset_index(inplace=True)` will do the job!

Comment: Good to know.  Can you post this as an answer (and accept the answer) so we can close the ticket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: `rrc3.reset_index(inplace=True)` will do the job!